# MouseUp event handler not working after MouseDown event is called on the same button WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a **show password button** in C# WPF Form, and what I want is:

- When user presses any mouse button (MouseDown event), the password from the `PasswordBox` becomes visible.
- When user leaves the mouse button press (MouseUp event), the password gets hidden again.

The issue is that the MouseUp event only gets fired if we don't perform a mouse button press (MouseDown) on that same `Button`. It means that, if we perform a **MouseDown** on the `Button` first, then **MouseUp** event will not be fired after that.

Here is XAML Code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="25" Height="25">
   <Image x:Name="showPassword_Button" Source="eye.jpg" MouseDown="showPassword_Button_MouseDown" MouseUp="showPassword_Button_MouseUp"></Image>
</Button>
```

Here is C# code of event handlers:

```
private void showPassword_Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    visiblePassword_TextBox.Text = password_TextBox.Password;
    visiblePassword_TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void showPassword_Button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // This function does not get called
    visiblePassword_TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    password_TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: The canonical way in WPF would be to set the Visibility in a Trigger or a Binding on the [IsPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed) property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following inside the `MouseDown` event handler function:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

When you perform a mouse down, the event does not get handled unless you release the mouse button. So it will block the **MouseUp event**.
You need to add `e.Handled = true;` inside the `MouseDown` event handler, to tell the program that event was handled.

The function `showPassword_Button_MouseDown()` should be written as:

```
private void showPassword_Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    visiblePassword_TextBox.Text = password_TextBox.Password;
    visiblePassword_TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    e.Handled = true; // Specify that event has been handled
}
```